# Add a task in WSO2 ESB configuration

Tags: xml, api, wso2, task, esb

I have to add a task (XML format) in WSO2 ESB configuration file without passing through ESB user interface. I write this xml externally in a Java-based application, then I should insert the obtained XML (it starts and ends with the `<task>` tag) into my Enterprise Service Bus. How to insert my task in a dynamic way (add, modify or delete task), in order to reach this goal in a safe way? Are there some WSO2 API that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use admin services : open CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml and set HideAdminServiceWSDLs property to false

Start ESB and you can now access to admin services wsdl.

You will find a service named "TaskAdmin" : https://localhost:8243/services/TaskAdmin?wsdl

It contains an operation named addTaskDescription, but I've never used it, hope it will help you.

If you want the list of admin services, you can start the Carbon server with -DosgiConsole option to go to the osgi console. If you type help in the console, you will get all the commands available.

listAdminServices command will list all the available services.

Perhaps this sample will help you : this javascript offers you a way to start / stop a schedule task from inside a mediation :

```
 <script language="js">importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse);
    importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse.config);
    importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse.task);
    var sc = mc.getConfiguration();
    var task = sc.getStartup("TestTask");
    var td = task.getTaskDescription() 
    td.setCount(0);
    //td.setCron(null);
    task.setTaskDescription(td);            
    sc.updateStartup(task);
    mc.setConfiguration(sc);
    task.destroy();
    task.init(mc.getEnvironment());</script>
```

If your task has a Cron expression, with td.setCount(0), task execution stop and with td.setCount(-1), task execution restart.

With td.setCount(1) + td.setCron(null), when you edit your task in ESB Console, you can observe that definition has been updated : Trigger Type changed from 'Cron' to 'Simple' (with count=1 and interval=0). Definition is changed in memory and lost when you restart the ESB

Comment: Have a look there : https://buddhimawijeweera.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/calling-wso2-esb-admin-services-using-jaggery-app/

Comment: Thank you, Jean-Michel. I'm trying to understand how to use your suggest. I changed the value of the flag in the configuration file but i can't find TaskAdmin among Services, I don't know hot to use it. Yesterday i gave a look at this https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Writing+Tasks , it seems to be present a way for adding tasks after creating pure java classes.

Comment: Writing tasks is a way to develop your own custom task in java. I thought your need was to add a new scheduled task at runtime ?    For your information, I can find TaskAdmin in ESB v4.8.1    If it can help you, I have an exemple in javascript that you can execute inside a mediation and that offers you a way to stop / start a scheduled task (so, probably, that can be extended to create a new scheduled task inside a mediation)

Comment: Where did you find TaskAdmin? In Main-Services-List? I can't find it. I need to create new task in Java, and to add them on the ESB . I saw in the overmentioned documentation page that xml-format is not mandatory in order to send them into the ESB source configuration file. I need to create classes (.jar files) and add them in the exact folder, but i'd like to know if someone has already added them anyway. Thank you for your support, i think your javascript example could be very useful, too.

Comment: Have you tried with https://localhost:8243/services/TaskAdmin?wsdl ?   For javascript and list of admin services, I will update my answer...